# Windows Phone 7 XNA GUI Framework

Tags: .net, user-interface, windows-phone-7, controls, xna

I write some application on XNA for Windows Phone 7. I need to use GUI Controls like comboBox, listBox, radioButton, etc. But XNA standart doesn't contains GUI Control. There are frameworks or libraries with GUI Control for XNA Windows Phone 7 application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the [App Hub FAQ page on the subject](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/15274.aspx).  It lists many options, including:

- XPF - a full layout engine. No price details yet. Works on phone too
- OrbUI - 27 controls, 3.1 and 4.0 support on PC and Xbox
- Nuclex Framework has a skinnable UI
- NeoForce controls discontinued but source for PC/XNA 4.0 is available on codeplex
- 2DNA
- GUI by Valentin
- Xwinforms
- GuiManager
- Simple Gui
- Window System for XNA
- Controls for ZuneHD
- XNA Interface Elements

Answer (score 2):

Last two days I have been playing with [Dynamic UI](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/dynamic_menu) and [User Iterface sample](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/ui_controls).

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://nuclexframework.codeplex.com/